# How to unit test Canceling a dialog that returns to MainDialog using the interupt dialog

Tags: c#, unit-testing, botframework

We are building a bot that has a MainDialog, and a subdialog. The subdialog inherits from a CancelAndHelpDialog. We want to return to the MainDialog when we type cancel in the subdialog. This all works, but when we try to unit test this, the test throws an exception:

> System.Exception : DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(): A dialog with an id of 'MainDialog' wasn't found. The dialog must be included in the current or parent DialogSet. For example, if subclassing a ComponentDialog you can call AddDialog() within your constructor.

I have setup a project at git that reproduces the problem:

https://github.com/Rufus1123/CancelReturnsToParentTestExample

I have taken the `CoreBotWithTests` template as a starting point. The change I have made is in the `CancelAndHelpDialog`. The `InteruptAsync` function now contains

```
await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
return await innerDc.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(MainDialog), null, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Instead of

```
return await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
```

in the case for "cancel" and "quit"

As the error suggests, the `MainDialog` cannot be found when we pass the `subdialog` to the `testclient`. We have tried adding the `MainDialog` to the sut in the test:

```
var sut = new BookingDialog();
var sut.AddDialog(new MainDialog());
var testClient = new DialogTestClient(Channels.Test, sut, bookingTestData.InitialBookingDetails, _middlewares);
```

but to no avail. The `MainDialog` still cannot be found

The way we now test if each dialog returns to `MainDialog` is by starting in main (passing mainDialog to the testClient), then navigating to the dialog that we want to test (with utterances in the DialogTestsDataGenerator), and finally test if "cancel" indeed returns to MainDialog, and shows the starting message. 
I would expect we would not need these steps, and only test our subdialog by passing it to the testclient. Is there a way to only pass the subdialog to the testclient, but still test if it returns to MainDialog?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a new dialogset in your DialogBot and add your MainDialog to that dialogset to solve your problem.

```
  Dialogs = new DialogSet(conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogBot<T>)));
  Dialogs.Add(new MainDialog());
```

Or just change the code in "cancel" from

```
await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
return await innerDc.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(MainDialog), null, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

to

```
return await innderDc.EndDialogAsync(nameof(YourSubDialog), cancellationToken);
```

and in your MainDialog, end it with this code so everytime you cancel it closes the sub dialog and it returns to the last step of main dialog and the last step restarts main dialog:

```
return await stepContext.ReplaceDialog(nameof(MainDialog), cancellationToken);
```